# How to scale and change background of Google Map marker with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to animate the scaling of the marker icon instead of just changing it to another icon with javascript?

I'ved added multiple markers to my Google Map as so:

```
var houseIcon = {
    path: 'M0,12h4.5V7.5h3V12H12V6L6,0L0,6V12z',
    fillColor: '#ff4b3d',
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    scale: 1,   
    strokeColor: '#ff4b3d',
    strokeWeight: 1
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position    : latlng,
    map         : map,
    id          : 'post-'+marker_id,
    icon:  houseIcon
});
```

I wish to be able to scale the icon and preferrably also change it's backgroundcolor when I hover a html element located outside the Google Map.

I've used the setIcon() method to change the background ..but I'd like to, if possible, animate the scaling of the icon instead of just displaying a bigger icon.

Here is my current hover function:

```
$('.my-element').hover(

      function() {
        data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        for( i= 0; i < map.markers.length; i++ ){
            if( map.markers[i].id== 'post-'+data_id){            

  map.markers[i].setIcon("path-to-bigger-icon");

            }
        }
      }, function() {
            data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        for( i= 0; i < map.markers.length; i++ ){
            if( map.markers[i].id== 'post-'+data_id){
                map.markers[i].setIcon("path-to-small-icon");               
            }
        }

      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using [RichMarker](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker) and attaching my events to the content elements added to the marker.